# Loop subroutine for every used row using multiple dynamic cell references

Tags: email, excel, vba

Basically what I am trying to do is, sending an email for every used row on the target worksheet, each row has the details of the addresses, subject line, table with values etc.

So I can't seem to get it working, as it only dispatches one email from the first target row (2nd row).

I have tried using a combination of `For Each` and `For i = 1 to LR` which aren't working. I suspect it is to do with the cell references.

Here is the code:

```
Sub TestEmail1()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim aOutlook As Object
    Dim aEmail As Object
    Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String
    Dim ccAddresses As Range, ccCell As Range, ccRecipients As String
    Dim rngeSubject As Range, SubjectCell As Range, SubjectContent As Variant
    Dim rngeBody As Range, bodyCell As Range, bodyContent As Variant
    Dim Table1 As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
      Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      LRow = rng.Rows.Count
      For i = 2 To LRow
        Set Table1 = Worksheets(1).Range("K1:R1")
        Set Table2 = Worksheets(2).Range("K" & i & ":" & "R" & i)
        Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

        'set sheet to find address for e-mails as I have several people to
        'mail to

        Set rngeAddresses = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
        For Each rngeCell In rngeAddresses.Cells
          strRecipients = strRecipients & ";" & rngeCell.Value
        Next

        Set ccAddresses = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i)
        For Each ccCell In ccAddresses.Cells
          ccRecipients = ccRecipients & ";" & ccCell.Value
        Next

        Set rngeSubject = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & i)
        For Each SubjectCell In rngeSubject.Cells
          SubjectContent = SubjectContent & SubjectCell.Value
        Next

        Set rngeBody = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i)
        For Each bodyCell In rngeBody.Cells
          bodyContent = bodyContent & bodyCell.Value
        Next

        'set Importance
        'aEmail.Importance = 2
        'Set Subject
        aEmail.Subject = rngeSubject
        'Set Body for mail
        'aEmail.Body = bodyContent
        aEmail.HTMLBody = bodyContent & "<br><br><br>" & RangetoHTML_   (Table1)            
        aEmail.To = strRecipients
        aEmail.CC = ccRecipients
        aEmail.Send
        Exit Sub
      Next i
    Next c
    End Sub
```

Comment: Define "can't seem to get it working". What result do you get, and how does that differ from the expected result? Do you get an error? What does it say? Also, please reduce that wall of code to a smaller sample that still demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry, so the problem is that it only dispatches one email for the first target row (2nd row) and missed the the rest of the other rows.

Comment: That is most likely due to the `Exit Sub` at the end of the inner loop.

Comment: Great Spot, Thanks Ansgar

Comment: Does that solve your problem, or does the code still not work as expected?

Comment: Yes it does. Cheers Ansgar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an `Exit Sub` at the end of your inner loop that makes the code exit from the procedure after the first iteration:

```
Sub TestEmail1()
  ...
  For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells
    ...
    For i = 2 To LRow
      ...
      Exit Sub
    Next i
  Next c
End Sub
```

Remove it and processing should continue as desired.